# C# converting UWP BitmapImage to WPF BitmapImage

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

I currently have a WPF application where I try to list all the icons for all UWP apps installed on the machine. For that I have referenced the UWP assemblies needed. Here's what I do:

1. I instantiate a `PackageManager`.
2. I call `FindPackagesForUser(string.Empty)` to give me all UWP apps installed.
3. For each app, I get all its list entries by calling `package.GetAppListEntriesAsync()`.
4. For each app list entry, I call `appListEntry.DisplayInfo.GetLogo(new Size(256, 256))`.

However, this returns a `RandomAccessStreamReference` which is a UWP stream for a `Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage` which is in turn the UWP version of a WPF `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage`.

How can I convert this stream's bytes into a WPF BitmapImage? Is there any documentation of how UWP stores these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open the RandomAccessStreamReference for reading to get an `IRandomAccessStream`, then call `AsStream` to get a `System.IO.Stream`:

```
using System.IO;
...

var streamRef = appListEntry.DisplayInfo.GetLogo(new Windows.Foundation.Size(256, 256));
var bitmap = new BitmapImage();

using (var randomAccessStream = await streamRef.OpenReadAsync())
using (var stream = randomAccessStream.AsStream())
{
    bitmap.BeginInit();
    bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmap.StreamSource = stream;
    bitmap.EndInit();
}
```